# Analyzing data in SPSS using ROC Curve For categorical variables (nominal)

Tags: spss, roc

I use SPSS v25 to build ROC.
I have DataSet  with the following data:

```
Case# Dosage  Result
1       DosagA  healthy
2       DosagA  sick
3       DosagB  sick
4       DosageC healthy
....
```

To analyse Using ROC, I encoded Result as:
Healty =1, sick =0

```
Case# Dosage  Result
1       DosagA  1
2       DosagA  0
2       DosagB  0
4       DosageC 1
....
```

When trying to build ROC with: Test Variable= result, State variable= Dosage

I get error message:

> String Variable are not allowed in the list

Do I have to Encode Dosage with numeric values like:

```
Case# Dosage  Result
1       1  1
2       1  0
2       2  0
4       3  1
...
```

Or
What is the best solution for ROC Curve using categorical   variables (nominal)?

Comment: just to make sure - after recoding a variable like `result` to "0", "1", you realize it is still a string variable, you need to change it into a numeric variable? If you didn't, you can use this: `alter type Result (f1).`

Comment: Result variable is numeric and Dosage is string.

Comment: Cross-posting is generally considered bad etiquette and discouraged on this site https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/491314/36682

Comment: @Calimo, the question is deleted on the other site.

Answer (score 0):

The prediction needs to be numeric. The ROC curve gives sensitivity vs. 1 - specificity for different cut points on a predictor, whether that's a single predictor or a score based on something like a logistic regression.